# Relation between cut families and existence of directed cycles

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I would like to know what you think of the following statement and, in case it is true, how would you prove it. Consider a directed graph $G=(V,A)$ where every vertex has degree higher or equal than three, and which contains an r-arborescence (a directed spanning tree); then

> the graph has a directed cycle iff for every maximal obstruction-free family of cuts $\mathcal{S}=\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{|V|}$ such that $S_i\subset S_{i+1}$, $\exists \tilde S\in\mathcal{S}$ with $|\delta^-(\tilde S)|\geq 1$ and $|\delta^+(\tilde S)|\geq 1$.

An obstruction-free family of cuts is here defined as a family such that $\forall S\in\mathcal{S}$, no subset of $\mathcal{S}\setminus S$ forms a partition of $S$. Furthermore, $\delta^+(S)$ is the set of outgoing edges in the boundary of $S$ and $\delta^-(S)$ is the set of incoming edges in the boundary of $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my reasoning are right then it took me more time to understand the statement than to prove it. :-) As I understood, the condition after “iff” is equivalent to that for any ordering $v_1,\dots, v_n$ of vertices of there exists $i$  such that $G$ contains edges $(v_j,v_{j’})$ and $(v_{k’},v_k)$ with $j,k\le i<j’,k’$. Now we can prove the statement for *any* directed graph $G$.

Assume that the graph $G$ has a directed cycle $C$. Then given an ordering of vertices of $G$  let $v_i$ be the first vertex of $C$ with respect to this order. Then the condition holds even for $j=k=i$.

Conversely, if $G$ is a directed acyclic graph then a [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Topological_ordering) of its vertices clearly violates the condition.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed at the end I managed to prove the second implication you mentioned (which was the difficult one for me) by explicitely showing a construction of the obstruction free-family by numbering vertices according to their appearance in paths (which turns out to be what you call topological ordering!) thank you for clearing my mind on this. Can you suggest more literature on the topic which i can read?

Comment: @Tanatofobico Unfortunately, I an not a deep specialist in this topic, but I expect that at the end of the linked Wikipedia page are some references.